# Operator Precedence Parsing via Insertion of Parens

Tags: python, parsing, operator-precedence

I've been working all night at trying to add operator precedence to my little toy experimental programming language I've been writing called [mio-lang[1](http://mio-lang.org/) and I've struggling to understand the basic algorithm despite it being clearly described to me by the likes of jer from the #io channel on FreeNode!

I'm trying to insert parenthesis into the token stream at the **right place(s)** and I believe this algorithm is called a Top-Down Descent Parser except I'm using a stack here rather than recursive function calls.

What follows is a naive cut-down snippet of the real thing:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


operators = OrderedDict([
    ("*", (2)), ("/", (2)),
    ("+", (1)), ("-", (1)),
])


def precedence(tokens):
    lparen = "("
    rparen = ")"

    level = None
    levels = []
    output = []

    while tokens:
        if len(tokens) > 1 and tokens[1] == "=":
            return tokens[:2] + precedence(tokens[2:])
        else:
            if len(tokens) > 1 and tokens[1] in operators:
                level = operators.get(tokens[1])

                if levels:
                    if level > levels[-1]:
                        levels.append(level)
                        output.append(lparen)
                else:
                    levels.append(level)

            output.append(tokens.pop(0))
            while levels and level < levels[-1]:
                level = levels.pop()
                output.append(rparen)

    while len(levels) > 1:
        level = levels.pop()
        output.append(rparen)

    return output
```

The full source code of this snippet plus some unit tests can be found here: http://codepad.org/2yNEp2Pr

Greatly appreciate some help in fixing my function and any edge cases!

Comment: I believe I have solved the two edge cases test8 and test8 by checking for ( and ) in the token stream and handling them in a special way. See: http://codepad.org/2yNEp2Pr -- Not sure if there's a better way to do this and if there are unforeseen other edge acases?

Comment: Problem with this modification, it matches too eagerly the next right parenthesis.

Comment: I'm still finding edge cases so if anyone can shed any light on this I'd appreciate it. One thing I've noticed is that I often get unbalanced parenthesis as a result.